Modelling vol for serial options for SOFR futures
Im trying to model the volatility for serial options on SOFR futures. I'm currently using SABR model to do this.
For a given date, I have both quarterly and serial options. I calculate implied normal vols for all options on a given date and calibrate SABR parameters.
The term structure across different expiries for each SABR parameter looks like this



The serial rank represents the type of option whether quarterly (0) or serial (1, 2)
I can interpolate on nu but alpha and beta are off for serial options. is there a way i can adjust the parameters for the serial options so that it gives a better interpolation?
